# codeigniter session not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have some problem with my codeigniter session. I am using CodeIgniter-3.1.8. I loaded session in autoload.php in config as

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

But it shows an error like `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`.

Then I removed it from autoload.php and load it in controller.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

And try to set `flashdata` in my controller. But now it shows error like `Undefined property: controller::$session`. I have already set the **encryption_key** in **config.php** and session storage driver to database.
Here is my sample code from controller :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function register() {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $result = false;     //$this->Home_model->register($data);
        if($result){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registration successful');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('form', 'login');
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('failure', 'An error occured, please try again');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('form', 'register');
        }

     }
}
```

This issue is coming,  when I am trying to load model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes needs to be done in config file.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

This issue is likely to be faced post CI migration. 
Make sure model name is declared correctly like

```
class Name extends CI_Model { }
```

First letter must be upper case in CI 3. save file in same name.

Another reason is sess_save_path. give correct path that should resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HHMVC please

```
class Home extends MX_Controller {}
```

instead of

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: i am not using HMVC. is this version strictly in HMVC?